# How to read Excel file, create a QR code?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I was trying with this code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import qrcode

wb = load_workbook("D:\QR\qrcodes.xlsx")  
ws = wb.['Sheet1']  
column = ws['A']  # Column
data = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]

print(data)
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version = 1, error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,box_size = 10, border = 4)

ext=".png"
for images in data:
    qr.add_data(i)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img=qr.make_image()
    img.save("{}{}".format(i,ext))
```

But after every loop the image created contains the value of the previous image also, how to solve that?

Comment: You don't appear to be using the value of `images` in the `for` loop.

Comment: It seems that the variable `i` is undefined, does this code actually run? Please clarify things.

Comment: sorry it was a typing error,  I used " i " only instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the QR object outside the loop.
You're better off initializing the object **<class 'qrcode.main.QRCode'>** inside your for loop **and** 
also using a **function to create your QR image** as variables inside a function have a local scope.

```
ext=".png"
def createQr(data):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version = 1, error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,box_size = 10, border = 4)
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img=qr.make_image()
    return img

for i in data:
    img = createQr(i)
    img.save("{}{}".format(i,ext))
```

Also as mentioned by [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) you have to change your loop variable from **images** to **i**

Comment: initialized the qrcode object inside the loop bt still the same problem is there

Comment: I have edited the answer. Let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please convert to csv. Then you should add enumerate so you will also have an index number for your file names instead of having multiple file.jpg.

```
import csv
import qrcode

with open('D:\QR\qrcodes.csv') as csvfile:
    fieldnames= ["Your_Column"]
    reader= csv.reader(csvfile)

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=10,
    border=4,
    )
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        labeldata = row[0]

        qr.add_data(labeldata)
        qr.make(fit=True)

        img = qr.make_image()
        img.save("test{}.jpg".format(i))
```

Comment: tried with csv also but the 1st qrcode contains the data of 1st cell but the last qrcode generated contains all the value of the column

Comment: @ansumangiri Could you please explain more. As I understood the first has one data the second has two and the third has 3 etc, is not it? If so just change your for loop and it will be correct...

Answer (score 0):

From an Excel file, it reads data in "A" columns starting from the second row and produces their QR codes, and creates a new excel file named "qrcode_produced" that has QR codes produced in the B column.

```
# modules needed
import qrcode
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#select the excel file to be read
# the texts must be in the "A" column starting with "2" row. In the B column, qrcodes will be seen.
print('select xlsx file:')
root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("xlsx files","*.xlsx"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)

# select the folder to save qrcodes as png format images and excel file with qrcodes
print('where to save excel file and qrcodes:')
root2 = Tk()
root2.withdraw()
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()

# read the excel file
workbook = load_workbook(str(root.filename))
sheet = workbook.active

# settings for qrcode to be produced
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=4,
    border=2,)

# excel file cell size settings that will be produced 
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 25
for i in range(1,len(sheet['A'])+1):
    sheet.row_dimensions[i+1].height=150

# Title of B column
sheet["B1"]="Qr_Codes"

# production of qrcodes for each row in the A column except first row. Skips the empty rows.
for i in range(2,len(sheet['A'])+1):
  if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value is None:
    continue 
  else:
    qr.add_data(str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value))
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image()
    img.save(folder_selected + "/" + "row_"+str(i)+"_qrcode.png")
    img=openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(folder_selected + "/" + "row_"+str(i)+"_qrcode.png")
    img.anchor = "B" + str(i)
    sheet.add_image(img)
    sheet["B" + str(i)].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
    sheet["A" + str(i)].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')


# saving the excel file
workbook.save(folder_selected+ "/qrcode_produced.xlsx")
```